# Alias template specialization issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>

template <class R1, class R2, class... RN> 
using ratio_sum = ratio_sum<ratio_sum<R1, R2>, RN...>;

template <class R1, class R2>
using ratio_sum<R1, R2> = std::ratio_add<R1, R2>;

int main()
{
    std::cout<<ratio_sum<std::ratio<3>, std::ratio<2>>::num<<std::endl;
}
```

It crashes with the following error:

```
main.cpp:5:23: error: expected type-specifier before 'ratio_sum'
using ratio_sum = ratio_sum<ratio_sum<R1, R2>, RN...>;
```

How to solve this problem ? (As it illustrates a generic problem, I dont want a workaround that uses `std::ratio_add` in the variadic version).

Comment: You can't partially specialize alias-templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code. The first, which you get, is that `ratio_sum<R1, R2>` is not defined when you try to use it. The solution to this is simple: Switch place of the two definitions.

The second problem is that you can not use templates when defining a type alias in the case of `ration_sum<R1, R2>`.